# How to detect a failure with subprocess in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a "cmd_to_execute" command which distributes workload across 2 different machines (machine1, machine2) and does some processing over data.
The Python code is executed on machine1.

If by chance machine2 shuts down during this processing, then the cmd_to_execute just aborts. I am trying to detect this by checking the return code "ret" of subprocess.call, but it is always "0". Also tried putting this around try-exception block, but do not see any exception.
Is there a way to do this in Python?

cmd_to_execute: a shell script

Python code:

```
ret = subprocess.call (cmd_to_Execute, shell=True)

if ret!= 0, retry
```

Comment: I hope that `if ret!= 0, retry` is just pseudocode, otherwise that is definitely incorrect.

Comment: Is `cmd_to_execute` a script that you wrote?  If so it is up to you to exit with the appropriate code in case of failure.

Comment: @0x5453, yes it's just a pseudocode.